# Facebook messenger sdk stickers

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger, facebook-messenger

Is it possible to send native stickers using Facebook Messenger's new API?

I tried using the following code, but the sticker is displayed as a downloaded image, rather than in native form

```
    messageData = {
        "attachment":{
            "type":'image',
            "payload":{
                "url":stickerURL
            }       
        }
    }
} else {
    messageData = {
        text:content
    }
}

request({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: {access_token:token},
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
    recipient: {id:sender},
        message: messageData,
        }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
    console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
    } else if (response.body.error) {
    console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the facebook chat bot API from https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api/, you can send a sticker like this:

```
 var msg = {
    body: "",
    sticker: 1433995916873384
  }
  api.sendMessage(msg, message.threadID);
```

But if anyone has a way to get more sticker IDs that would be awesome! Thanks for the one above @starshine wang

EDIT: To get sticker IDs, console.log the message object you get back from api.listen. It has type sticker

Answer (score 3):

For now it looks like not possible to send stickers by messenger bot. If you check the message data which contains a native sticker, it looks like this:

```
{ 
  mid: 'mid.14647894...',
  seq: 3199,
  sticker_id: 1433995916873384,
  attachments: [ 
    { 
       type: 'image',
       payload: { 
           url: 'https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xta1/t39.1997-6/p100x100/10173492_1433995920206717_978513924_n.png?_nc_ad=z-m' 
       } 
    } 
  ]
}
```

And it's different from the structure described on messenger bot guide (Note it has a *sticker_id* field).